# Jenkins plugin using class from another plugin, not Maven dependency

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I’m trying to overcome some dependency disparity through one of plugins, by removing dependency on jackson2-api plugin, and using direct jackson maven dependency instead.

Is it even possible to do something like that? because it seems not to work well.

https://github.com/cvakiitho/build-failure-analyzer-plugin/commit/c51ed3fbed62f7bb30a854ba8fcea5831649f1d2

BFA plugin still seems to use jackson classes from jackson2-api plugin, not direct maven dependency.
resulting in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-62214
where wrong jackson version is used in import inside MongoJack, resulting in missing method:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.Annotated.getGenericType()Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;
    at org.mongojack.internal.MongoAnnotationIntrospector.getTypeForAnnotated(MongoAnnotationIntrospector.java:81)
    at org.mongojack.internal.MongoAnnotationIntrospector.findDeserializer(MongoAnnotationIntrospector.java:97)
```

Is dependency from the Jackson2-api plugin somehow higher in classpath in jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

Can't answer you directly, but running [`mvn dependency:analyze`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html) and [`mvn dependency:tree`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) should guide you.

`analyze` reports:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:analyze (default-cli) @ build-failure-analyzer ---
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.2:compile
[WARNING]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.2:compile
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.jenkins-ci.plugins:jackson2-api:jar:2.10.2:compile
```

And `dependency:tree` reports (selective list):

```
[WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution
[INFO] com.sonyericsson.jenkins.plugins.bfa:build-failure-analyzer:hpi:1.27.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.sonyericsson.hudson.plugins.gerrit:gerrit-trigger:jar:2.27.5:compile
 ...
[INFO] +- org.jenkins-ci.plugins:slack:jar:2.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.jenkins-ci.plugins:jackson2-api:jar:2.9.9.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.10.2)
 ...
[INFO] +- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:3.8.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.mongojack:mongojack:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mongodb:bson:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.mongodb:bson:jar:3.8.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- de.undercouch:bson4jackson:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.9.9)
[INFO] |  +- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.jenkins-ci.plugins:jackson2-api:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:compile
```

So, the [dependency resolution](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) takes the direct / declared dependency will override the undeclared / transitive dependency (and the higher over the lower #.#.#).

Comment: Yeah, the thing is, I removed jackson2-api from all dependencies. 

`mvn dependency:tree | grep jackson2-api` - empty.

But the plugin is installed on the jenkins, so it's classes are globally available.
Guess some jenkins internals are making the classes > everything else in dependency tree.

Comment: From the BFA root pom.xml, you removed `org.jenkins-ci.plugins:jackson2-api:2.10.2`, but did you add `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.2` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.2` (or 2.9.9) as they are the only used dependencies? **What is the outcome**? ps: Approach seems counter to Jenkins providing the Jackson2-API wrapper. Seems the issue lies w/mongoDB as noted in the JIRA issue and should be addressed there.

Comment: Note that the [latest](https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-failure-analyzer-plugin/blob/d0775505256dda5b6345bde34aceb4e3cbea5861/pom.xml#L168) pom.xml excludes the direct dependencies of `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:*` on `org.mongojack:mongojack`, so they will be inherited from the "nearest", which would now be the BFA root `pom.xml`, via the `jackson2-api` reference. Failure to exclude would have it reference what was in the mongojack pom.

Comment: yeah I removed those: 
https://github.com/cvakiitho/build-failure-analyzer-plugin/commit/d6ce8fbbf0d3c421e4310437c1847a348294c2de 
no luck

Comment: **What is the outcome?**; same as above ? Your latest change still includes direct dependency on [`jackson2-api`](https://github.com/cvakiitho/build-failure-analyzer-plugin/blob/d6ce8fbbf0d3c421e4310437c1847a348294c2de/pom.xml#L169). Not sure which way you are trying to go here.

Comment: I probably don't get what you are asking, I already commented here, that jackson2-api is not in dependency tree after the changes I did originally.

Comment: I should have originally ask a different question, I have removed the jackson2-api from maven pom, and it is not in dependency tree, yet it gets loaded in runtime in the plugin. I'll update the question to be more clear about that.